# How to login to Iptorrents.com via python requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests

POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.iptorrents.com/login.php'

REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.iptorrents.com/t'

payload = {
    'username_input_username': 'ZZZZZZZZ',
    'password_input_password': 'ZZZZZZZZZ',
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
print(r.text)
```

I expected to show me the source of homepage of torrent but it just show the source code of login page .

Comment: You're `POST_LOGIN_URL` and `payload` are wrong.  
You need to send the request to `https://www.iptorrents.com/take_login.php` and the payload should be 
`{
    username: 'ZZZZZZZZ',
    password: 'ZZZZZZZZ'
}`   
But you won't be able to login, because the website is protected with CAPTCHA

Comment: whene i run the code i take this error :NameError: name 'username' is not defined

Comment: and  the web site dose not have CAPTCHA

Comment: surround username and password in the json with `'`

Comment: @CryNetPlan, no captcha all right, but the site is behind Cloudflare which checks your browser before allowing you to enter the site. Cloudflare WAF will effectively prevent you from entering the site without a standard browser.

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed you are using this link to login to the website

```
https://www.iptorrents.com/login.php
```

While its Not the API call that let the user login.
If you had noticed closely here's the Network call that Login the user to the website.

```
https://www.iptorrents.com/take_login.php
```

With Payload Structure as:

```
payload = {
    'username': 'zzzz',
    'password': 'zzzzzzzzz',
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by network call? Plus there is no such page as iptorrents.com/take_login.php.

Comment: There is no such page on website, it is API. Network call mean API call.
You can monitor API calls in any browser's inspector.

Comment: I get it but did you observe, that the site was running behind Cloudflare. If you have a working piece of code, post it in full.